# How to filter data when assigning a long list of parameter in tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I get a character object that includes ten names that I want to filter as to see all their rows.
How to send in given list of parameters in the function filter().

I have tried sending the character to the filter function, and only return one row.

```r
> head(ls)
[1] "xtyintao"    "蒙特多"      "stonezw"     "jackietz"   
[5] "qiaoxingmao" "champlin"   

nodes %>%
    filter(name==ls)

  name     outdegree totaltimes label1  label2 
  <chr>        <int>      <int> <chr>   <chr>  
1 jackietz         2          2 unknown unknown
Warning message:
In name == ls :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When filtering to see if an element `name` is in a vector `ls` you need to use `%in%` instead of `==`. `1 == 1` is true, but `1 %in% c(3, 2, 1)` is also true. But `1 == c(2, 3, 1)` returns `false false true` which is ambigous. Therefore, try this code:

```
nodes %>%
    filter(name %in% ls)
```